# Error while connecting to SQL database

Tags: java, sql-server, ssl, jdbc

I am getting the following error while connecting to the `MS SQL 2008 R2` from a specific server, from other severs it works fine.

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.".

The following is my code to connect to the database:

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db_info, db_userid, db_password);
```